# NUnit Assertion that enum value contains a flag

Tags: .net, nunit, flags

While writing some tests for our .Net (C#) libraries with NUnit, I came to following problem:
I have an enum which has the Flags attribute, e.g.

```
[Flags]
public enum Powers : int
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Zero = 1,
    One = 2,
    Two = 4,
}
```

Now I want to write an NUnit test for checking that

```
Powers aValue = Powers.One | Powers.Two
```

contains Powers.Two. Currently, I use

```
Assert.That((aValue & Powers.Two) == Powers.Two), "something went wrong")
```

But isn't there a more elegant way to do that?
Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx).

In your case:

```
Assert.That(aValue.HasFlag(Powers.Two), "something went wrong");
```

Note that this method is only available in *.NET Framework 4* and higher.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. SInce I use .Net 4, that's an abbreviation. I actually thought of something similar to the CollectionAsserts, e.g. a EnumAssert.HasFlag(expectedFlag, actualValue, message) - is there something like that?

Comment: Do you mean a method for checking all expected flags in one go? As far as I know, there is no such thing implemented in NUnit, but it should be fairly straightforward to come up with some replacement. I'll give it some thought.